# SELECT query to fetch records from table since last fetch based on last updated time

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want to create a select query that fetches 100 records from a table based on the last updated field.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE lastupdated > 'xxxx'
ORDER BY lastupdated ASC
LIMIT 100
```

I will then want to run this query again later with the last updated time from the last record.

What if the 101st record had the same lastupdated value as the 100th record in the first set? This will lead to the next fetch missing that record right?

How do I ensure that I don't duplicate or miss records in the next fetch? Would adding an id column and filtering by id as well solve the issue?

Comment: in MySQL you can use a `TIMESTAMP` field which can have a resolution out to milliseconds. In SQL-Server it's `DATETIME2`. But it's still theoretically possible (although unlikely) that you will have two records with the same timestamp. So, yes, an `IDENTITY`ID column would solve that.

Comment: Your query has no `ORDER BY`.  That is confusing when using `LIMIT`.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. Added Order By.

Comment: @DavidBeckman - Trying to create a generic solution.

Comment: @daShier - Would adding order by id have issues if the queue gets reordered later with changes in lastupdated?

Comment: If your `ID` column uses an `IDENTITY` attribute ('AUTO_INCREMENT' in MySQL), then they will always be in ascending order regardless of updates. You can't update the `ID` column, so the order never will change.